# Кросскомпиляция из под Linux на Windows C++ gtk3

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gtk

Я скачал mingw на Linux и скомпилировал обычный Hello, world! для Windows всё получилось!

Но мне нужно скомпилировать с библиотекой gtk+-3.0:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -o main.exe `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

widget.hpp:1:10: fatal error: gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
1 | #include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>

Вопрос, как мне подключить gtk+-3.0.

Comment: Посмотрите [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662215/how-do-you-install-gtk-3-0-on-windows)

Comment: А мой ответ не сработал? Если там что-то не завелось, баг-репорты приветствуются. :)

Answer (score 4):

GTK3 для винды есть в [репозиториях MSYS2](https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/). Сам MSYS2 не работает под Wine, но пакеты можно скачать и распаковать вручную (но придется вручную определять и ставить зависимости их тех же репозиториев - это долго).

---

На правах саморекламы: я сделал [скрипты](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2), которые автоматически качают пакеты из этих репозиториев вместе с нужными зависимостями, и заодно вписывают пути к ним в нужные переменные окружения.

Инструкции по использованию есть в readme.

Минимальный пример выглядит так:

1. Читаем readme, ставим необходимые программы. На данный момент нужны `make`, `wget`, `tar`, `zstd`.
2. Устанавливаем сами скрипты, и качаем ими пакеты.

   Все устанавливается в текущую папку. Никакого мусора нигде не остается, эту папку потом можно просто стереть.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2
   cd quasi-msys2
   make install _gtk3
   ```
3. Теперь ставим нужные переменные окружения командой `source env/vars.src`.
4. Компилируем почти так же, но передаем в `pkg-config` флажок `--define-prefix`.

   ```
   x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -o main.exe `pkg-config --define-prefix --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
   ```

   Результат работает под вайном.

   Флажок нужен потому, что в `.pc`-файлах (из которых `pkg-config` берет флаги) этих пакетов  пути написаны с расчетом на то, что пакеты стоят в `/mingw64`, а у нас это не так. Этот флажок исправляет пути на настоящие.

   Вместо этого флажка надежнее будет сделать `/mingw64` ссылкой: (путь поменяйте на тот, куда клонировали репозиторий)

   ```
   sudo ln -nfs "/home/holyblackcat/quasi-msys2/root/mingw64" /mingw64
   ```

---

Но можно сделать еще лучше.

По крайней мере в репозиториях убунты `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` - слегка старый, 9.x. А вот репозиториях MSYS2 есть новенький GCC, который прекрасно работает под Вайном, но работает медленно.

Есть отличный вариант: поставить MSYS2 GCC только ради библиотек, которые идут с ним в комплекте, а кросс-компилировать уже Clang-ом, с помощью этих библиотек. Любая сборка Clang-а (в отличие от GCC) умеет кросс-компилировать под любую поддерживаемую архитектуру, поэтому просто ставим обычный Clang для линукса.

Дальше ставим пакеты:

```
git clone https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2
cd quasi-msys2
make install _gcc _gtk3
```

На всякий случай делаем `/mingw64` ссылкой (нужно исправить путь на свой, см. выше зачем нужна ссылка):

```
sudo ln -nfs "/home/holyblackcat/quasi-msys2/root/mingw64" /mingw64
```

Теперь запускаем `env/shell.sh`, и если все сделано правильно, то кланг должен запускаться командами `win-clang` и `win-clang++`, сразу со всеми флажками, нужными для кросс-компиляции.

**Предупреждение:** `env/shell.sh` кроме прочего настраивает ядро для прозрачного запуска экзешников через Wine (в консоли будут работать вещи типа `./foo.exe`). Эта настройка сохраняется до ребута.

Для этого скрипт спросит пароль для `sudo`. Если рандомным скриптам из интернета нет доверия, то можно отказаться вводить пароль (Ctrl+C), ввести ту же команду руками, потом набрать `sudo -k` - чтобы `sudo` забыл только что введенный пароль, чтобы скрипт ничего не выполнил с этим сохраненным паролем. А потом перезапустить скрипт.

Или, если эта фича не нужна вообще, можно вместо `env/shell.sh` использовать менее продвинутый `source env/vars.src`, как в первом примере. Расковыряйте файлы, почитайте readme, посмотрите что за что отвечает, и какие именно фичи вам нужны, а какие нет.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл проблему, просто скачайте бинарные файлы и перекинте их в директорию где расположен mingw. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8d1qbh5dsp044on/AAANpCYDILO-G2gPeth0x-Vwa?preview=gtk%2B-gtkmm-3.22.0-mingw32-6.2.0-posix-dwarf.7z